# How can I enter one query into another model based on the information in the json on torchserve?

Tags: rest, pytorch, torchserve

I want to serve multiple models on the same server with 4 GPUs via torchserve.
And I hope that 4 different models will be served on each GPU.

##### Information about my environments

I think this is not an issue about the runnig or error, but just simple programming.

##### What I'm wondering now

1. Is it possible to enter one query into another model based ond the informaion in the json on the server?
2. If possible, how can I do that?

##### What I tried before

1-1. Load multiple model on 1 custom handler file
   1-2. Enter the input to different models with the model information from the json

2-1. Make 4 different handlers for 4 models
   2-2. I can't implement it properly due to poor skills...

##### What I expected to happen

1. The query is preprocessed to determine properly which model to input before inference.

##### What actually resulted

1. I'm sorry I can't make any results.

Thanks for your help in advance!